# React setTimeout and setState inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, use-effect

I have this code and my question is why inside my answer function I get the initialState. How to set the state in a proper way to get the right one inside a callback of setTimeout function?

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    password: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({ ...state, password: "hello" });
    setTimeout(answer, 1000);
  }, []);

  const answer = () => {
    console.log(state);
    // we get initial State
  };
  return <div className="App"></div>;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is closure.

`answer` function will always log that value of `state` which `setTimeout()` function closed over when it was called.

In your code, since `setTimeout()` function is called when `state` contains an object with empty values, `answer` function logs that value, instead of logging the updated value.

To log the latest value of state, you can use [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook. This hook returns an object which contains a property named `current` and the value of this property is the argument passed to `useRef()`.

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const stateRef = React.useRef(state);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = { ...stateRef.current, password: 'hello'};
    setState(stateRef.current);
    setTimeout(answer, 1000);
  }, []);

  const answer = () => {
    console.log(stateRef.current);
  };
  return <div></div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: One problem with this code is that we have to update  state 2 times hm..

Comment: no, state is only updated once, `stateRef` object is not the state of your component but you will have to update `stateRef` when you want to update the `state`

Comment: yeah, thats what I`m talking about

Comment: You could create a function that updates the `stateRef` and `state` and just call this function whenever you want to update the state

Answer (score 0):

The function `answer` is a closure other the value of state, it captures the value of a variable inside of it's scope when it's defined. When the callback inside of useEffect is called, the answer method it's got is closed over the value of the state before your setState.

That's the function with whom you'll be calling `setTimeout` so even if there's a timeout, the old value of the state will be delay.