# not getting the correct value from React.useContext within React.useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-context

I'm quite new to React but playing with it since a few weeks.

I'm building a music playlist app.
When a track is clicked, it firsts checks (API) if it has audio sources availables.
If yes, it plays the track; if not, it goes to the next one.

Thing is, sometimes, while the API request is made, the user clicks another track.

In my track component, I thus want to compare the track index with the context track index, to check if we still have to play the first track requested once it has its API response.

The problem is that, when I compare the two values within a useEffect function, it gets the wrong value (old state?) for the context track index.

My code is quite complex so I made a simple example here.

*In my reducer:*

```
  case 'SET_TRACK_INDEX':
  console.log("(Context) SET TRACK INDEX TO: " + action.payload)
  return {
    ...state,
    trackIndex:action.payload
  }
  break;
```

*In my track component:*

```
const [playlistData, setPlaylistData] = useContext(PlaylistContext);

//function called when I click the track
const onToggleTrack = () => {
  //set index to "1" in the context
  setPlaylistData({
    type: "SET_TRACK_INDEX",
    payload:1
  });

  //after one second, change index to "2" to simulate user action
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      console.log("(onToggle) waited two seconds and change index...");
      setPlaylistData({
        type: "SET_TRACK_INDEX",
        payload:2
      });
    }, 1000
  );
}

//runs when context index is updated to "1"
React.useEffect(() => {

  // (run this test for the track "1" only)
  if (playlistData.trackIndex !== 1) return;

  console.log("(useEffect) TRACK INDEX IS NOW: "+ playlistData.trackIndex);

  const index = playlistData.trackIndex;

  const testIndexes = () => {

    setTimeout( //simulate an API request delay
      function(){
        console.log("(useEffect) Now context index should have been updated to '2', check values...");
        console.log("(useEffect) THIS INDEX: " + index + " VS CONTEXT INDEX: " + playlistData.trackIndex);
      }, 4000
    );

  }

  testIndexes();


}, [playlistData.trackIndex]);
```

This is what I get in the console :

```
(Context) SET TRACK INDEX TO: 1
(useEffect) TRACK INDEX IS NOW: 1
(onToggle) waited two seconds and change index...
(Context) SET TRACK INDEX TO: 2
(useEffect) Now context index should have been updated to '2', check values...
(useEffect) THIS INDEX: 1 VS CONTEXT INDEX: 1
```

So, as you can see, I should/want to get

```
(useEffect) THIS INDEX: 1 VS CONTEXT INDEX: 2
```

But I get

```
(useEffect) THIS INDEX: 1 VS CONTEXT INDEX: 1
```

Maybe the context value are "frozen" when useEffect is fired ?
How could I fix this ?

Thanks !

By the way, here my real code :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (track !== playlistData.trackRequested) return;

  setApiLoading(true);
  track.prepareSources()
  .then(function(){
    console.log("SOURCES READY FOR TRACK " + track.jspf.title + " by " + track.jspf.creator);

    track.getNextPlayableSource()
    .then(function(nextSource){

      console.log("REQUESTED: " + playlistData.trackRequested.jspf.title + " by " + playlistData.trackRequested.jspf.creator);
      console.log("CURRENT: " + track.jspf.title + " by " + track.jspf.creator);

      if (playlistData.trackRequested === track){ //double check this is still the requested track
        setPlaylistData({
          type: "REQUEST_SOURCE",
          payload:nextSource
        });
      }

    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log("BWERK")
    })

  })
  .catch(function(err){
    setPlaylistData({
      type: "TRACK_ERROR"
    });
    console.log("SKEEEEP TRACK");
    skipToNextTrack();
  })
  .finally(function(){
    setApiLoading(false);
  })

}, [playlistData.trackRequested]);
```

Comment: In your current case, the problem (not the problem actually, this is the expected behavior) is `setTimeout`. This happens because of closure. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62920594/react-settimeout-and-setstate-inside-useeffect). I doubt that you are using `setTimeout` in your actual code, so saying something about your problem is difficult. You should provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or the better one is providing [a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look and will try to paste a full example.  Indeed I do not use setTimeout, but still, I get the wrong value.

Comment: @devserkan : I added the real code at the end of my  post.

Comment: I found out how to do by reading this post : https://blog.bloomca.me/2017/12/04/how-to-cancel-your-promise.html

Comment: I haven't seen your previous comment, sorry. I'm glad that you found the solution. By the way, you can answer your own question and explain the details.