# React Custom hooks calling useState multiple times

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux

Custom Hook,

```
const useMyHook = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(true);

    const changeState = () => {
        setState(false);
    };

    const logState = () => console.log(state);

    return { changeState, logState };
};
```

Component,

```
function App() {
    const { changeState, logState } = useMyHook();

    useEffect(() => {
        changeState();
        setTimeout(logState, 2000);

        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return <>...</>
}
```

But in the output giving always `true` which is the initial value even after I am changing it by calling `changeState` inside `useEffect`.

Dependencies:

- Node Version: **18.14.2**
- Yarn Version: **1.22.19**
- React version: **18.2.0**

Answer (score 1):

In your case `logState` is a closure which keeps a reference of the `state` variable at the time it is created. When you use `setState` to alter that state, the state reference changes, but `logState` still "remembers" the old one.

You need to use `useCallback` which exists for this purpose:

```
const useMyHook = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(true);

    const changeState = () => {
        setState(false);
    };

    const logState = useCallback(() => console.log(state), [state]);

    return { changeState, logState };
};
```

This will create a new `logState` instance with a new `state` variable whenever the `state` variable changes. You don't need to do that with `changeState` because `setState` is always the same reference.

However the new problem is that now even though `state` changes your `setTimeout` is still calling the old "remembered" `logState` but since this changes you will need a new effect:

```
function App() {
    const { changeState, logState } = useMyHook();

    useEffect(() => {
        changeState();
    }, []);
    useEffect(logState, [logState]);

    return <>...</>
}
```

This should call `logState` whenever `state` changes (i.e. a new instance of `logState` is created.

Comment: Then how will I config the ```setTimeout```?

Comment: @NaveenMuraliAV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62920594/react-settimeout-and-setstate-inside-useeffect might give you an idea but in general it's not an easy task